# Changing Time formats

Tags: javascript, python, datetime

How do I change a datetime format from "2021-07-08 06:35:14.013135" to "2021-07-08T14:35:14.123+08:00" using Python and Javascript codes?

I have tried the following in Python:

```
now = datetime.now().isoformat()[:-7]
nowZ = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
now_utc = datetime.utcnow()
now_utc_s = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
now_utc_ms = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
```

And obtained:

> now: 2021-07-08T14:35:14
> nowZ: 2021-07-08T14:35:14Z
> now_utc:2021-07-08 14:35:14.123135

> now_utc_s: 2021-07-08 14:35:14
> now_utc_ms: 2021-07-08 14:35:14.123

How do I get "+08:00"?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

It explains every parameter and what it does. You can look to use the UTC offset parameter `%z`.